# Vue.js 3 and Tailwind CSS: Dynamic width not rendering correctly in RatingBar component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

I am using Vue.js 3 with Tailwind CSS. I have a component named RatingBar, and I'm trying to apply a dynamic width value to the parent  element's class. However, even though I can see the desired width in the DevTools, it renders the width as 100%.

Here is the code in my `RatingBar.vue` component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="my-2 grid grid-cols-3 items-center">
    <span class="text-left text-sm">{{ genre.name }}</span>

    <div class="h-2 flex-1 rounded-lg bg-gray-800">
      <div
        class="h-full rounded-lg bg-secondary"
        :class="`w-[${Math.floor(genre.rating * 10)}%]`"
      ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ml-2 flex flex-row items-center gap-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
      <i class="fa-regular fa-star"></i>
      <span class="flex flex-row gap-1">
        <span>
          {{ genre.rating }}
        </span>
        <span> ({{ genre.count }}) </span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  genre: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
})
</script>
```

The rendered HTML output shows the width as `w-[75%]` inside the `<div>`:

```html
<div class="h-full rounded-lg bg-secondary w-[75%]"></div>
```

And here is my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "firebase": "^9.22.1",
    "vue": "^3.3.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.2.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.3.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "vite": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Could you please help me resolve this issue?

I tried using static values for the width in the RatingBar component, and it rendered correctly. However, when I attempted to use dynamic values for the width by using the expression `:class="w-[${Math.floor(genre.rating * 10)}%]"`, the rendering didn't work as expected. Instead of applying the calculated width, it always rendered with a width of 100%.

I expected the div element with the class bg-secondary to have a width corresponding to the calculated percentage based on the `genre.rating` value. For example, if `genre.rating` was 7.5, the width should have been 75%.

Despite verifying the width value in the DevTools, the rendered HTML output consistently displayed the width as 100%, regardless of the actual calculated value.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and get the dynamic width to render correctly in the RatingBar component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

Instead, you could use the `style` attribute to set the `width`:

```js
<div
  class="h-full rounded-lg bg-secondary"
  :style="{ width: `${Math.floor(genre.rating * 10)}%` }"
></div>
```